# Import BLOB (Image) from oracle to hive

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import BLOB(Image)data form oracle to Hive using below Sqoop command.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@host --username --password  --m 3 --table tablename  --hive-drop-import-delims  --hive-table tablename --target-dir '' --split-by id;
```

But unsuccessful. Remember, BLOB Data stored in oracle database as Hexadecimal and we need to store this to Hive table as text or bianary.

What are the possible way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop does not know how to map blob datatype in oracle into Hive. So You need to specify  `--map-column-hive COLUMN_BLOB=binary`

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@host' --username $USER --password $Password  --table $TABLE  --hive-import --hive-table $HiveTable  --map-column-hive COL_BLOB=binary --delete-target-dir --target-dir $TargetDir  -m 1 -verbose
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help. 

When we are trying to load the hexadecimal data (BLOB) to HIVE as binary, it is working fine. But when we trying to show the data using Select query, we found corrupted binary data (like '?',',' etc) stored in HIVE table.

I also observed that after run the sqoop command, Hexadecimal data are storing in HDFS, but as HIVE does not support Hexadecimal data, Its trying to convert the HEX data into binary and corrupting all data when we execute any select query.

Comment: The data is not been corrupted, however it is the hive console which is not able to show it properly. Export the same data in RDBMS and then apply select with $where condition you will get appropriate record.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Did you resolve this ? I think that exporting from hive to rdbms is not what people want to do. Most of the time it's from rdbms to hive..