# How to import images to HDFS? I am using CDH version 5.11

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have sqoop, flume and spark installed on my system but I am not sure how to import image files.

I am able to import data from RDBMS using sqoop, successfully and I am able to import text files using flume.

How do I import images on hdfs?

Comment: Where is your images located?

Comment: image is on some remote server and i am trying to import images.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop doesn't have a concept of file type (like Windows does, for example) so you can use any tool to import images into Hadoop.

If you have images in a BLOB column, you would use SQOOP.

Flume supports binary data so you could use BlobDeserializer.

> BlobDeserializer
>
> This deserializer reads a Binary Large Object (BLOB) per event, typically one BLOB per file. For example a PDF or JPG file. Note that this approach is not suitable for very large objects because the entire BLOB is buffered in RAM.

In HDFS, the basic commands `-put` or `-copyFromLocal` will work.

```
$ hdfs dfs -put about.png /tmp
$ hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/about.png
-rw-r--r--   3 testuser supergroup      53669 2017-06-30 11:34 /tmp/about.png
$
```

Or you can use the WebHDFS APIs to do this remotely.

References:

[Import BLOB (Image) from oracle to hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703129/import-blob-image-from-oracle-to-hive)
https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#blobdeserializer
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Create_and_Write_to_a_File