# What is the best way to store Blob data type in a Hive table, as a string or Binary?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

What is the best way to store Blob data type in a Hive table, as a string or Binary?

We have archived RDBMS table into Hive using Sqoop. Which is having a column of type BLOB, So in Hive we kept in Binary. But We are not able to read the binary content into PDF or any document. So Do we have any possibility to read that Hive binary data as a document?

Storing BLOB data into Hive Binary is recommendable approach or do we have any other ways?

Is there any Big data Component like HBase,Cassandra will support BLOB types?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use HIVE binary to store blob data into HIVE. You can follow the below link [Import blob from oracle to HIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703129/import-blob-image-from-oracle-to-hive)

You can also use Cassandra or parallel nosql to store the blob data. Again it's based on your use case whether to chose HIVE or nosql databases.